# Axios seems bypass both .then/.catch and triggered .finally directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using React(16.13.1) with Axios(0.19.0) and encounter a weird situation...

Multiple `console.log()` were set for trying to figure out the problem.

```
  const signUserAPI = async (data) => {
    console.log('top of the function')
    await setIsFetching(true);
    await setIsError('');

    axios.post(
      apiPath.signUpPath,
      { user: data },
    ).then((response) =>{
      console.log('then')
      console.log(response)
      setIsSuccess(true)
      }   
    ).catch((e) => {
      console.log('catch')
      setIsSuccess(false);
      setIsError(e);

      if (e.response) {
          ...
      }

    }).finally(() => setIsFetching(false), console.log('finally'));
  };
```

when `axios.post` is fired, I supposed to get the contents with console.log() in the following orders

```
// in console

'top of the function'
'then'
'response content...'
'finally'

// OR

'top of the function'
'catch'
'finally'
```

but what I really get were

```
// at 1st render
'top of the function' 
'finally'

// at 2nd render
'then'
'response content ...' 

// OR

// at 1st render
'top of the function'
'finally'

// at 2nd render
'catch'
```

Looks like axios bypassed `then` or `catch` and went into `finally` directly at the first render, and was bypass `finally` at the second render.

Dose anyone has the same experience or can explain to me what's happened ...

I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write your `finally` callback correctly, i.e.

```
() => {
  setIsFetching(false);
  console.log('finally');
}
```

As written both lines are executed, but the console.log is executed immediately and isn't included with the callback. It's a comma delineated list of expressions that all get evaluated and the last is returned.

Example of finally block callback issue

```js
(setTimeout(() => console.log('hi'), 2000), console.log('test'))
```

[comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The **comma operator** (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left to
>   right) and returns the value of the last operand. This lets you create
>   a compound expression in which multiple expressions are evaluated,
>   with the compound expression's final value being the value of the
>   rightmost of its member expressions.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote wrong cod in finally block, use below changes

```
const signUserAPI = async (data) => {
    console.log('top of the function')
    await setIsFetching(true);
    await setIsError('');

    axios.post(
      apiPath.signUpPath,
      { user: data },
    ).then((response) =>{
      console.log('then')
      console.log(response)
      setIsSuccess(true)
      }   
    ).catch((e) => {
      console.log('catch')
      setIsSuccess(false);
      setIsError(e);

      if (e.response) {
          ...
      }

    }).finally(() =>{ setIsFetching(false); console.log('finally');});
  };
```

Comment: Got it ! Thank you,  Md Mahamudul Hasan